# Can I test the difference between two chi square statistics for significance

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, mcnemar-test

I'm working on a (currently) hypothetical problem that relates to monitoring and evaluating people's participation in recycling. The test statistic is the participation rate (the proportion of households that set out recycling for collection at least once every 3 weeks).

There are a number of things I might want to do with this statistic:

- Establish a confidence interval for a given participation rate using the binomial approximation.
- Compare two areas with one another using the binomial approximation for the difference between two proportions.
- Compare an area before and after some intervention using McNemar's test.

But there are two areas where I am unclear:

- If I do a pre and post intervention measurement on a paired sample, can I use the binomial approximation to produce an interval for the difference between the two participation rates, or does the matched sample foul this up?
- How would I test a pre and post intervention experiment with a trial and control area, looking at the differences in the observed changes in the two areas? This is the one that is bugging me more, and I've considered two options here:

Option 1: Try to use the binomial approximation for the difference between the observed changed. This difference is given by p(trial_post)-p(trial_pre)-p(control_post)+p(control_p).
This approach seems to lead to large sample sizes being needed, as I need to add the variance of all four samples when calculating the standard error of the difference in the two observed changes (and, as above, I'm not even sure this is valid if the samples are matched).

Option 2: The other thing I've been toying with is McNemar's test again. Is there a way to test the *difference* between two McNemar  test statistics (one for a trial, one for a control) for significance in a way that is analogous to (for example) comparing two regressions using ANOVA?

I know the result of the McNemar test is a chi square , and that the sum of two chi squares is itself a chi square, but that's where my knowledge runs out. Does the same hold true for the *difference* between two chi squares (or does this not work because chi square is always positive) and if it does what happens to the degrees of freedom? Am I missing the point completely and there's a much easier approach?

Any thoughts on this much appreciated.

Thanks,

Billy.

Comment: Maybe best to address _one_ item at a time, with more context, clearer explanation. // What do you mean by "binomial approximation"? (Approx of binomial by normal?) // One thing for sure: "[T]his [does] not work because chi square is always positive."

Comment: Hi Bruce - thanks for the feedback. That was a bit rambling. I did mean the approximation of the binomial by the normal).
I think maybe it would be better to back off what I have tried and to ask the question in it's basic form. I'm struggling for words, but something like:
"What is the simplest and most appropriate way to compare a treatment response between two groups (a trial and control) when each group is itself represented by a paired sample (before and after treatment)? The variable of interest is binomial."